# Add different texts to divs with same id using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 5 divs with `id="correctAnswer"`. I have an array of 5 elements. How to add these 5 elements in 5 divs. I have this logic.

```
var answers =["David Bowie","AM","Australia","Boneface","Sound City"];
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    document.getElementById("correctAnswer").innerHTML="correctanswer:"+answers[i-1];
}

<div id="correctAnswer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use same ID. ID MUST be unique!!

Comment: You can't re-use IDs...use a class instead.

Comment: Or - use getElementsByTagName, if that will work for you. It would be easier to answer if you posted your HTML code too.

Comment: "id" comes from "identify" or "identifier". How can something be an identifier, or identify anything, if there are five of them?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 2):

First of all, never use same IDs. NEVER. Use classes instead. It should go like this:

```
<div class="correctAnswer"></div>
<div class="correctAnswer"></div>
<div class="correctAnswer"></div>
<div class="correctAnswer"></div>
<div class="correctAnswer"></div>

<script>
var answers =["David Bowie","AM","Australia","Boneface","Sound City"];
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName("correctAnswer")[i-1].innerHTML="correctanswer:"+answers[i-1];
}
</script>
```

Comment: As Mehul said you cannot use the same id, id should be unique!